# trouble Insering Arraylist into a fragment

Tags: android, arraylist, fragment

Good evening guys, I am trying to have a swiping tab app with `ArrayList` inside some of them, but when I try to make a simple one like this :

```
public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {
    public static ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private EditText recipient;
    private EditText textMessage;
    private static ListView listview;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

        // BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);

    // @Subscribe
    // public void anotherButtonPress(ButtonEvent event) {  
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity ", "Fragment reads me !");
        // String newtime=event.itime;
        // String newname=event.name;
        // messages.add("("+newtime+") "+newname+":");
        // messages.add(event.text);
        // setListAdapter();
        messages.add("hellooo");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.id.list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I get this error :

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215): Process:    
com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample, PID: 5215
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at   
com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample.GamesFragment.on
CreateView(GamesFragment.java:61)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions
(FragmentManager.java:1478)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at    
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions
(FragmentManager.java:     478)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at 
 android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-28 09:37:43.530: E/AndroidRuntime(5215):     at   
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, could you guys help me here? Thanks.

Comment: Null pointer exception is in 61-st line: com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample.GamesFragment.on
CreateView(GamesFragment.java:61) Check your code in debugger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't intiliaized the listView object but, all the same, you are accessing it. You need

```
listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't handle the **ListView** yet

write thid line before calling the Adapter method

```
listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.????)
```